# .htaccss wild card redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, wildcard, redirect

I have my .htaccess code as follows :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/aboutus
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/aboutus [P] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contactus
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/contactus [P]        
</IfModule>
```

Individually all works fine , but i need a wild card redirection .That is , 
I want to redirect all the request follows the pattern of h`ttp://www.mydomain.com/{mystring}` to `http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/{mystring}` . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule (?!^admin/loadhomepages/)^(.+)$ /admin/loadhomepages/$1 [P,NC,L]
```

Comment: This is looping through the site , and site is never loading . i think there is only needed aboutus,contactus parts to modify

Comment: You need to comment out your earlier aboutus,contactus rules.

Comment: Made an edit, try now. Is that all of your .htaccess or you have something else also?

Comment: I have the code remove the index.php also as am in codeigniter:RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] , but thats not affecting the above

Comment: May I ask why are you using `P` (Proxy) flag ?

Comment: I dont want to change the url on the go , so as i copied from another question

Comment: will this work ? RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/$1 [P] i got stucked ,help

Comment: okay ,let me try ,now my .htaccess look like this :        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (?!^admin/loadhomepages/)^(.+)$ /admin/loadhomepages/$1 [P,NC,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    
</IfModule>               its never completing the request , is browser is caching something

Comment: NOw it is: The requested URL /admin/loadhomepages/admin/loadhomepages/admin/ etc...      Not found error

Comment: Is this .htaccess in some subdir of DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Its on the same directory of application,system,css,js ...in codeigniter. But there is an .htaccess inside application , the htaccess i edited is outside the application ,on the document root ,and under public_html in cpanel

Comment: Oh I see, I don't know much about codeignoter but I suspect multiple rules are overlapping and causing this unexpected behavior.

Comment: The project will run as first : application->views->index

Comment: Sorry I know quote a bit about mod_rewrite but this CI is new beast for me. Unfortunately I won't be of much help further since above rule works in my standalone Apache.

Comment: Yeah , now i got the problem !! when i remove the code to remove index.php on routing it works fine for the above rule ! ,But i want to work it together , thats index.php/aboutus , index.php/contactus etc.... are all working fine , but not www.mydomain.com/aboutus

Comment: But i need to show www.mydomain.com/aboutus in the url ,not www.mydomain.com/index.php/aboutus ,Thats i need to remove index.php on routing (thats a crap in CI ), and so only www.mydomain.com/aboutus works , but these rules are overlapping

Comment: You can try adding this rule: `RewriteRule (?!^index.php/)^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]` but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I done with routes in CI , but its like senetence by sentence ,so was i tried htaccess , but there should be a mechanism in CI for not overlapping these rules

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^aboutus$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/aboutus [L] 
    RewriteRule ^contactus$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/contactus [L]        

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/admin/loadhomepages/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But i need a wildcard redirection that suites all the strings in places of aboutus,contactus etc..